# How to parse xml with simplexml - nodes with spaces & non standard format

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

A simple xml node shown below and im OK looping through atom feed and grabbing the title all pretty simple.

```
<title>Soft Golden Yellow Champagne Wedding Fizzy Bubbles </title>
```

My problem is with nodes like this one where its not formatted like the simple ones:

```
<link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="https://someimage.com/image.jpg"/>
```

How do you store and echo that out? My code to grab the titles below

```php
$html = "";
$url = "https://www.redbubble.com/people/honorandobey/shop/recent+drawstring-bags.atom";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i =0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $title =$xml->entry[$i]->title;
    $html .="<p>$title</p>";
}
echo $html;
```

How do you grab images/links or anything that's formatted like that link rel node?

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd strongly recommend you read through [the basic SimpleXML examples in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) you can access attributes of a node as an array, so to get for example the `href` attribute of the `link` tag, do this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i =0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $title =$xml->entry[$i]->title;
    $html .= "<p>$title</p>";
    $html .= "<p>Link: ".$xml->entry[$i]->link["href"]."</p>";
}
echo $html;
```

Or you can also access the attributes using the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
$html .= "<p>Link: ".$xml->entry[$i]->link->attributes()->href."</p>";
```

Comment: OK That works but can you explain why that's NOT grabbing the image ? as that node is also called link.

Comment: What do you mean? You have the URL there, what else do you need?

Comment: no it works fine ,Thanks. "href attribute of the link tag" got it.  im wondering how your code is not picking up line 19 (my feed) where there is a similar node that has "link tag" +  "href" in it?  `<link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.501707466.2898/drawstring_bag,x1404-bg,ffffff.u2.jpg"/>
    <category term="design"/>`

Comment: Oh, right, the first matching element is selected by default. To get the second one (the one with the image), use `$html .= "<p>Link: ".$xml->entry[$i]->link[1]->attributes()->href."</p>";`

Comment: OK you just save my MAC, it was about to go through the window THANKS